# Regular expression query (runtime customizable)

Tags: java, regex

I have a special requirement, my regular expression pattern will be determined at run time for say i have a date and will like it to be checked against `mm-dd-yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` or `d.mm.yyyy` something basically  i would be feeding the pattern as `NN-NN-TTTT` where `N` mean a number and `T` means a letter and the expression can be anything. Can we write any regular expression that will work for this kind of requirement?

my form will look like as displayed in http://jsfiddle.net/E2EHZ/ data will matched corresponding to pattern specified in the text box

`T` - letter
`N` - Numeric
`A` - Alphanum

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples of what you're after?

Comment: As I see it, `T` is also numeric, isn’t it?

Anyway, date validation done purely in regular expressions is unreliable, to say the least.

Comment: @MPi - it need not be a date that was just an example

Comment: Is T alphanumeric or only letters?

Comment: `T` will be only letters

Comment: Will have `A` for alphanum... sorry missed that in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially you would have your users enter a pattern containing `T`, `N` or `A` as placeholders with other characters that need to match literally in between? If so, then it's rather easy: Just replace your placeholders by appropriate character classes, quote the rest (so regex metacharacters are escaped) and use the result as a regex.

First escape everthing that is *not* `A`, `N` or `T`. How to do this varies by language, but essentially you'd replace `[^ANT]+` by an escaped version of the match. In C# it might look like this:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "[^ANT]+", m => Regex.Escape(m.Value));
```

or in Java:

```
s.replaceAll("[^ANT]+", "\\Q$0\\E"
```

The translations to perform then are easy:

```
T → [a-zA-Z]
N → [0-9]
A → [0-9a-zA-Z]
```

That is, assuming ASCII-only. For Unicode you might want

```
T → \p{L}
N → \p{Nd}
A → [\p{L}\p{Nd}]
```

instead. Also note that if you perform simple string replacements you'll need to replace `A` first with the ASCII versions and `N` first for the Unicode variants to avoid replacing it in subsequent results.

In the end you might want to prefix your string with `^` and suffix it with `$` if you want to match complete strings.

A sample implementation in C# (with a tiny optimisation):

```
string CreateRegex(string pattern) {
  string result = Regex.Replace(pattern, "[^ANT]+", m => Regex.Escape(m.Value));
  result = Regex.Replace(result, "A+", m => "[0-9a-zA-Z]" + (m.Length > 1 ? "{"+m.Length+"}" : ""));
  result = Regex.Replace(result, "T+", m => "[a-zA-Z]" + (m.Length > 1 ? "{"+m.Length+"}" : ""));
  result = Regex.Replace(result, "N+", m => "[0-9]" + (m.Length > 1 ? "{"+m.Length+"}" : ""));
  return "^" + result + "$";
}
```

which for example results in the following:

```
NN-NN-TTTT → ^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{4}$
*(@&#^(&%(@  AA-AA-NN-TTTTTTTT lreglig → \*\(@&\#\^\(&%\(@\ \ [0-9a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{8}\ lreglig
```

Or in Java (without said optimisation, because I cannot figure out how to use a function as replacement):

```
String createRegex(String pattern) {
  String result = pattern.replaceAll("[^ANT]+", "\\Q$0\\E");
  result = result.replaceAll("A", "[0-9a-zA-Z]");
  result = result.replaceAll("T", "[a-zA-Z]");
  result = result.replaceAll("N", "[0-9]");
  return "^" + result + "$";
}
```

The resulting regexes will be a bit longer because the code above won't use repetition for identical tokens.

Comment: Yes, it will. You need to adapt the actual code a little, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: What is `s` in the answer `string result = Regex.Replace(s, "[^ANT]+", m => Regex.Escape(m.Value));`

Comment: See the edit. The Java code is untested but might work. But as I said, the general idea is the same; it just looks slightly different in syntax ;)

Comment: It's a typo and should be `pattern`.

Comment: Ah, you might need `"\\\\Q$0\\\\E"` for the replacement there.